# How to play an mp3 using fancybox

Tags: fancybox

I am adding fancybox to my page and to display different types of formats. I was able to implement video, text, and images seamlessly but when it doesn't load the audio. Once I click on the audio file on the gallery it opens on a blank page. I am trying to play the track as iframe if possible.

```html
<!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
<li class="item-thumbs span3 music">
  <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
  <a class="hover-wrap" data-fancybox-type="iframe" data-fancybox-group="music"
     title="Breathin'" href="breathin.html">
    <span class="overlay-img"></span>
    <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
    <p class="description">
      <span class="title">Song</span>
    </p>
  </a>
  <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
  <img src="_include/img/Breathin'200.jpg"alt="Breathin'">
</li>
<!-- End Item Project -->
```

I just added a player for my audio files but I have not figured out how to add them to fancybox. There are multiple files that I would like to add in the same format as above where an icon is showing and once pressed the fancybox will open up the player. Here is the player and it works perfect(outside of fancybox).

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>breathin.html</title>
<link type="text/css" href="plugin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4a: "_include/download/Breathin'.m4a",
            oga: "_include/download/Breathin'.ogg"
          });
        },
        swfPath: "plugin",
        supplied: "m4a, oga"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
      <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
        <ul class="jp-controls">
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a> </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="jp-progress">
          <div class="jp-seek-bar">
            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-volume-bar">
          <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-time-holder">
          <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
          <div class="jp-duration"></div>
          <ul class="jp-toggles">
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-title">
        <ul>
          <li>Breathin'</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="jp-no-solution">
        <span>Update Required</span>
    To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Anyone have any ideas??
  Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: what do you use to play video? you may need a player for the audio too

Comment: For video I am using fancybox-media. but it does not play audio.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo..